# NHibernate: Mapping a one-to-many relation in a SQL View

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working with a SQL view, and I don't know enough about NHibernate, views, or databases in general, to know where my problem lies.  The view I'm working with used to have a string column, "ExemptionCode".  Now, the view can potentially have many exemption codes.  Here is the XML mapping for the new relation:

```
<class name="LatestDocumentVersion" table="LatestDocumentVersion" mutable="false" schema-action="none">
    <id name="DocumentVersionID" type="Int32"/>        
    <property name="ContainerDocumentID" type="Int32"/>
    <!--<property name="ExemptionCode" length="10" />-->
    <set name="ExemptionCodes" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="false">
      <key column="ContainerDocumentID"/>
      <one-to-many class="ContainerDocumentExemptions"/>
    </set>
    <--Properties omitted-->
</class>
```

Here is the mapping for the ContainerDocumentExemptions class:

```
<class name ="ContainerDocumentExemptions" lazy ="false">
  <id name ="ContainerDocumentExemptionID" type="Int32">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="ContainerDocumentID" class="ContainerDocuments" column="ContainerDocumentID" cascade="none"/>
  <property name="ExemptionCode" length="10"/>
</class>
```

The ContainerDocumentExemption class actually has a bi-directional one-to-many relationship with a ContainerDocument object.  Here's the other end:

```
<class name="ContainerDocuments" lazy="false" table="ContainerDocuments">
    <id name="ContainerDocumentID" type="Int32">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <!--<property name="ExemptionCode" length="10" />-->
    <set name="Exemptions" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="true">
      <key column="ContainerDocumentID"/>
      <one-to-many class="ContainerDocumentExemptions"/>
    </set>
    <--Properties omitted-->
</class>
```

After adding this line to the ContainerDocuments class, ContainerDocuments can correctly write to and read from the new ContainerDocumentExemptions table:

```
public class ContainerDocuments {
    public virtual ISet<ContainerDocumentExemptions> Exemptions { get; set; }
    //Properties omitted
}
```

So, I added this code to the LatestDocumentVersion class:

```
public class LatestDocumentVersion {
    public virtual int ContainerDocumentID { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<ContainerDocumentExemption ExemptionCodes { get; set; }
    //properties omitted
}
```

LatestDocumentVersion is a view that performs inner joins and outer joins on a bunch of different tables, and takes a bunch of different columns from each.  (The SQL that creates the view is very complicated, and it's hopefully irrelevant to the problem at hand.)  The newly added LatestDocumentVersion.ContainerDocumentID, which is a foreign key into the ContainerDocumentExemptions table, always populates correctly.  However, the ExemptionCodes collection always remains empty.

I have a feeling that part of the problem is the ContainerDocument back-reference in the ContainerDocumentExemptions class.  Could this prevent me from using the same mapping in the LatestDocumentVersion class?  I thought that making the LatestDocumentVersion-ContainerDocumentExemptions relation uni-directional would mitigate that issue, if it were a problem.  So how can I populate the LatestDocumentVersion.ExemptionCodes field??  Could anyone at least give me hints as to how to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContainerDocumentID` is the id on the `ContainerDocument` class but it is not on the `LatestDocumentVersion` class and by default each one-to-many joins back on the id. Add `property-ref` to the `LatestDocumentVersion` mapping

```
<class name="LatestDocumentVersion" table="LatestDocumentVersion" mutable="false" schema-action="none">
    <id name="DocumentVersionID" />
    <property name="ContainerDocumentID"/>
    <set name="ExemptionCodes" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="false">
      <key column="ContainerDocumentID" property-ref="ContainerDocumentID"/>
      <one-to-many class="ContainerDocumentExemptions"/>
    </set>
</class>
```